# 2nd table row's start date fail to grab the result date in the 1st row

Tags: jquery

When the 1st row of date change,its result date will show accordingly.
The issue is the 2nd row of start date is suppose to grab the 1st row result date and change according to its skip days and show its own result date.

```js
$('input.date, input.day').on('change',function() {

  var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
  
  var start = $row.find('.date').val();
if (start) {

  var set = new Date(start);

  set.setDate(set.getDate() + Number($row.find(".day").val()));

  $row.find(".result").val([set.getMonth() + 1, set.getDate(), set.getFullYear()].join('/'));
  
  $row.next('tr')
        .find('.date').val([set.getMonth() + 1, set.getDate(), set.getFullYear()].join('/')).trigger('change');  
  
  
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="one">
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Skip days</th>
  <th>Result</th>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="date" class="date"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="10" class="day"> </td>
      <td><input type="text" class="result"> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="date" class="date"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="5" class="day"> </td>
      <td><input type="text" class="result"> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Result

```
 14/10/17      5     19/10/17
 19/10/17      3     22/10/17
```

Comment: Because the 2nd row Date is getting  deleted  hence Nan

Comment: care to elaborate a bit,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set date value to `input type date` in `year-month-date` format.

Change the line:

```
$row.next('tr').find('.date').val([set.getMonth() + 1, set.getDate(), set.getFullYear()].join('/')).trigger('change');
```

to

```
var dt = set.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + (set.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + set.getDate()).slice(-2);
$row.next('tr').find('.date').attr('value', dt).trigger('change');
```

and it will work.

```js
$('input.date, input.day').on('change', function () {
 var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
 var start = $row.find('.date').val();
 if (start) {
  var set = new Date(start);
  set.setDate(set.getDate() + Number($row.find(".day").val()));
  $row.find(".result").val([set.getMonth() + 1, set.getDate(), set.getFullYear()].join('/'));
  var dt = set.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + (set.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + set.getDate()).slice(-2);
  $row.next('tr').find('.date').attr('value', dt).trigger('change');
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="one">
 <th>Date</th>
 <th>Skip days</th>
 <th>Result</th>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <input type="date" class="date"></td>
   <td><input type="text" value="10" class="day"> </td>
   <td><input type="text" class="result"> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td>
    <input type="date" class="date"></td>
   <td><input type="text" value="5" class="day"> </td>
   <td><input type="text" class="result"> </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: input type is not really relevant to the problem

Comment: it only when the 1st time when i try to change the start date, but fail at the 2nd time , any idea?

Comment: In the above snippet I can change start date in first row multiple times and other dates change accordingly.

Comment: tried several time, still the same, sometime when  i select the date on the 1st row , the 2nd row start date fail to grab the 1st row result date

Comment: for example, when i change the 1 st row start date for the 5 th time, it fail to response

Comment: thumb up for yr help

Comment: Hmm...verified in chrome it works fine, but in IE have problems. Anyway, updated my code above now.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Snippet with **Minimum Code Manipulation** with respect to your code.
Just added another function and its good

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<table id="one">
  <th>Date</th>
  <th>Skip days</th>
  <th>Result</th>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="date" class="date"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="10" class="day"> </td>
      <td><input type="text" class="result"> </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="date" class="date"></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="5" class="day"> </td>
      <td><input type="text" class="result"> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<script>
 
 
function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}


 $('input.date, input.day').on('change',function() {

  var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
  
  var start = $row.find('.date').val();
    
if (start) {
 
  var set = new Date(start);

  set.setDate(set.getDate() + Number($row.find(".day").val()));

  $row.find(".result").val([set.getMonth() + 1, set.getDate(), set.getFullYear()].join('/'));
   
   
   var rawDate= [set.getMonth() + 1, set.getDate(), set.getFullYear()].join('/');
   var strformat =formatDate(rawDate);    
  
   $row.next('tr').find('.date').val(strformat).trigger('change')
}
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: okayyy ....so you want result of 1st date to be the start of 2nd date...& so on...am i correct ?